# Coffeescript rewrite function

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, return, anonymous-function

I have a following function that has to be generated from Coffeescript:

```
$("#user-tabs ul").idTabs({
    click: function(id, all, container, settings) {
        alert(id);
    } 
});
```

So, I got the following coffeescript written:

```
$("#user-tabs ul").idTabs ->
    click: (id, all, container, settings) ->
       alert(id)
       return
```

But it doesn't work. At the output (.js) I got following code generated:

```
$("#user-tabs ul").idTabs(function() {
  return {
    click: function(id, all, container, settings) {
      alert(id);
    }
  };
});
```

So, the click function is written properly, but it is being wrapped by some "function-return" closure. How to rewrite it to reach the desired code (at the very top) ? Is it possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't `->` for defining functions in CoffeeScript? Therefore you defined it in the first line. Try to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just indent the object, don't make it a function (what `->` does).

```
$("#user-tabs ul").idTabs
    click: (id, all, container, settings) ->
       alert(id)
       return
```

[See it](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3a%20%20%20%20%24%28%22#user-tabs%20ul%22%29.idTabs%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20click%3a%20%28id,%20all,%20container,%20settings%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert%28id%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%20).

Comment: All i can say: DOOOOOOH! That was so simple. Silly me! Thank you so much! :P

Answer (score 1):

Drop the -> which *defines* a function (you just want to *call* it):

```
$("#user-tabs ul").idTabs 
    click: (id, all, container, settings) ->
       alert(id)
       return
```